# Probability of $\lambda$ given k, in Poisson distribution.

Tags: probability

We know the PMF of poisson distribution is $P_K(k) = e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda ^k}{k!}$, now, given $k$ arrivals in a unit time, what is the PDF of the arriving rate being $\lambda$?

Comment: I don't know this notation: What does $K$ stands for?

Comment: It means $P(K=k)$, $K$ stands for the random variable, $k$ stands for the value of $K$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such thing unless you specify a prior. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Bayesian_inference) has a section that gives a conjugate prior for this problem.

Comment: Thanks. This is kind of deep for me at the moment.

Comment: @CravingSpirit: OK; to put it in more mundane terms: What you think about $\lambda$ after you learn that there were $k$ arrivals in a unit time depends on what you that about $\lambda$ before you learned that. For instance, if you think *a priori* that very low values of $\lambda$ are very unlikely, then even after you observe $0$ arrivals the probability you assign *a posteriori* to low values of $\lambda$ will be less than the probability you would have assigned *a posteriori* after observing $0$ arrivals if you had *a priori* believed these low values to be quite likely.

Comment: Ok, you mean the probability of $\lambda$ depends both on our *a priori* judgment and the value of $k$.

Comment: @CravingSpirit: Yes, that just about summarizes it :-)